# Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed with a formula

Tags: excel, vba

This is my VBA code:

```
Sub AutoRunMacro()
    Range("N5").Formula = "=SUM(COUNTIF(F5:M5;""*Pending*"")+COUNTIF(F5:M5;""*Rejected*"")+COUNTIF(F5:M5;""*Expired*"")+COUNTIF(F5:M5;""*Incomplete*"")+COUNTIF(F5:M5;""*Empty*"")) / COUNTIF(F5:M5;""<>*N/A*"")"
End Sub
```

Every time I open this file, the macro is executed, but this error shows up:

```
Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed
```

Do you guys know how to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: You should use `,` instead of `;` if using `Range.Formula` but that error message seems to suggest another line not in your current code is failing.

Comment: Well it actually stops in the formula line, i'll try what u said

Comment: Wow yes, it worked, by the way, do you know if I can format cells as a percentage in my formula?

Comment: Also the outer `SUM` is superfluous.

Comment: `Range.NumberFormat = ....`?

Comment: `Range("N5").NumberFormat.Formula =` ? It's my first time using VBA sorry

Comment: `Range("N5").NumberFormat = "0.00%"`

Comment: Actually the first time I open the file doesn't work, it works when I close it and reopen it. Maybe it executes the formula before filling the table with data.

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't describe a specific problem or error. Seems like you may want to ask a new question with all relevant code, including the problem, error message, or unwanted behavior.

Comment: Well, doesn't work, it appears the same error `Run-time error '1004' : Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed`, but ok, I'll try it in another question thanks.